# Is wudu broken if a dog touches your trouser?

Tags: wudu

As a delivery driver I was at a customer's house and a dog came out and touched my trouser. It was isha time and I was rushing to go to the mosque for salat. I performed the salat with the imam but forgot to do wudu as I did wudu at magrib prayer. Was my wudu broken when the dog touched my trouser, or is it okay?

Answer (score 1):

Touching the fur of the dog will not break your wudu, 
if however the salvia of the dog touches your hand or clothing in this case you would have an impurity and it should be washed before salat.

Forgetfulness wil not count it as a sin but you
Should repent anyway and ask for forgiveness to be safe.

See [link 1](http://www.onislam.net/english/ask-the-scholar/acts-of-worship/purification/impurities-and-methods-of-purification/175183-a-dog-touched-my-clothes-how-to-cleanse-them.html?methods_of_purification=) and [link 2](http://www.shiachat.com/forum/topic/234978318-dogs-hair-najis/)

God knows best.